# jQuery Cross Domain AJAX Reference Error

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have been trying to make use of the World Bank API by performing cross domain AJAX requests on their API. As listed on their [developer page](http://data.worldbank.org/node/11), the basic call syntax would be:

> http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?format=jsonP&prefix=Getdata
>   *Note: For JsonP format, 'prefix' parameter needs to be specified.*

The following is the stripped down version of what I use in my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/'+req.indicator+'?
                 format=jsonP',
            dataType: 'jsonP',
            jsonp : "prefix",
            success : function(res){

            console.log("Success");
            console.log(res)
            var count = res[0].total;

        if(requestdata['per_page'] == 1){

                request(req, count);
            }
            else{
                var grid = formatResponse(res);
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
```

However I run into this error every time by taking a sample indicator, say, ***SP.DYN.CDRT.IN***:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery17209248960050754249_1390249074104 is not defined

If it helps, the console output is:

```
Error
success
*undefined*
200
Error {}
```

I guess the above reference is made to the anonymous callback used in jQuery calls.
I'm clueless why isn't it working though. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your Console's Network tab show for the call to that domain? What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Linux. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6788073/) is the response I get in the network tab

Comment: Is that supposed to be a JSON string?

Comment: Yes, JSON with Padding. I guess Rocket's answer pointed out the error, it was on the API developer's side

Comment: Kudos to Rocket Hazmat, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the API you are calling.  They are ***incorrectly*** creating the JSONP response.

jQuery is passing a callback name of `jQuery123456_7890`, but the API is trying to call `jquery123456_7890`.  Functions in JavaScript are case-sensitive.  The API is ***wrongly*** converting the function name to all lower-case, no idea why.

You need to workaround this problem by telling jQuery to use an all lower-case callback name.  That's what the `jsonpCallback` parameter is for.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/'+req.indicator+'?format=jsonP',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: "prefix",
    jsonpCallback: "jquery_"+(new Date).getTime(),
    success: function(res){
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(res)
        var count = res[0].total;

        if(requestdata['per_page'] == 1){
            request(req, count);
        }
        else{
            var grid = formatResponse(res);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Comment: Nicely spotted, Thanks! I guess I should pass on the message to the API developers as well

Comment: @AshwiniKhare: Glad I could help! :-D  Yeah, I would let them know their API is generating incorrect responses :-)